# How to save user info in aws dataset after facebook/google sign in

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've logged in with social media in federated identity aws and i want to save the user info like email, picture, and name user after sign in with dataset from aws. How to save it? i'm looking for example but i still confused
i need more example for it

Comment: get started with following samples https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples. you will get more info about it

Comment: Dev from the Cognito team here, +1 to the samples. They'll show you exactly how to do it. This might also be helpful: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/synchronizing-data.html